# Close a jQuery dialog, from inside a user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a user control including a list view that includes a hyperlink (LnkDelete) to popup a jQuery dialog.

**This is the javascript code that does the work**

```
$('#LnkDelete').live('click', function (e) {
            var page = $(this).attr("href");
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 600,
                    title: "Are you sure you want to delete ...?"
                });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

**This is the hyper link that opens the "DeleteBranch" web form as a dialog:**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="LnkDelete" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "~/Personnel/DeleteBranch?Id={0}") %>' ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="button-delete" />
```

The "DeleteBranch" web form includes a user control with "Ok" and "Cancel" *ASP buttons*.
The "Ok" button simply performs the delete operation of the related row in the original listview.

The question is:
How to make the "Cancel" button closes the popup?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#LnkDelete').live('click', function (e) {
        var page = $(this).attr("href");
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 200,
                width: 600,
                title: "Are you sure you want to delete ...?",
                buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'OK',
                    click: function() { /*Your delete operation*/ }
                },
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function() { $dialog.dialog('destroy'); }
                }
               ]
            });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

As you said, in case of your *ASP* buttons, give that button a `ID` like `btn_cancel` and add the following script:

```
<script lang='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_cancel').click(function(){
        $dialog.dialog('destroy');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use the default buttons of the Dialog. Actually, I said that I'm using ASP buttons, that perform further server side actions. I want these buttons to be able to close the dialog.